# loading a specific UIViewController from AppDelegate when receiving UILocalNotification

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller, uilocalnotification

I got a **UILocalNotification** that is sent within a **UIView** part of a **UIViewController** in this way:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:_localNotif];
```

I would like my App to respond to it in the following occasions:

- when in background: if user taps on notification awake the App and load corresponding UIViewController (there is more than one UIViewController)
- when in foreground: refresh data in current UIViewController

The documentation leads me to modifying this method within **AppDelegate.m**:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification: (UILocalNotification *)notification {

    NSLog(@"received notification");
    //reload views
}
```

However I have no idea on how I can reload a UIViewController.

- What properties of UILocalNotification can I use to determine which
  UIViewController sent it?
- How can I load a specific UIViewController from AppDelegate?

Answer (score 0):

> What properties of UILocalNotification can I use to determine which
>   UIViewController sent it?

You can use the `userInfo` property of `UILocalNotification` for this specific purpose. So, something like:

```
localNotification.userInfo = @{ @"currentViewController" : self }; // put the instance of the current view controller into the userInfo dictionary
```

> How can I load a specific UIViewController from AppDelegate?

You can access your current view stack through the `rootViewController` property of your application's main `UIWindow`, which is stored in the `window` property of your `AppDelegate`. If you just want to *notify* your `UIViewController` that a local notificaiton was received, you can post a `NSNotification` and add the view controller that should be reloaded as an observer to that particular `NSNotification`

So, e.g. when you receive the `UILocalNotification`, the code could look somewhat like this:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification: (UILocalNotification *)notification {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"received_local_notification" object:nil];
}
```

And the, in `viewDidLoad` of the `UIViewController` that is to be reloaded:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(reloadTheViewController:) name:@"received_local_notification" object:nil];
}
```